# Oracle snapshot too old on static data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I have a report that is run overnight. Previously the report held hard coded variables in the select clause, however now I want to read from a table of static data.

So far I have created a new table which is used in the report and prior to the report being run a delete from and insert into and commit; happens.

Here is the process:

```
@sql/regenerate_table.sql
spool data/report.csv
@sql/report.sql
spool off
quit;
```

regenerate_table.sql looks like this:

```
delete from schema.static_table_used_in_report@dblink;

insert into schema.static_table_used_in_report@dblink select * from
schema.master_table@dblink;

commit;
```

The report is then along the lines of;

```
select x,y,z from 
(select x,y,y from @db1 where not in select * from     
schema.static_table_used_in_report@dblink
union all
select x,y,y from @db2 where not in select * from
schema.static_table_used_in_report@dblink
union all

etc.
group by x, y, z;
```

Currently the data in schema.static_table_used_in_report is the same as the hard coded values in the previous report, however the previous report took around 1 hour, whereas the snapshot too old is happening around 4 hours after it has started. I have tried timings on hardcoded vs dblink and there isn't any appreciable difference between the two.

It was my understanding that undo was only required when consecutive queries / transactions are taking place - since no other data is using the schema.static_table_used_in_report@dblink table it shouldn't be required for read consistency purposes as they can be read and re-read directly from the disk.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://perfstat.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/ora-01555-snapshot-too-old-and-delayed-block-cleanout/

Comment: Look at the execution plans of the two queries, particularly the newer one. Are all the tables you're querying remote? Is there a reason to have the static-value table remote too?

Comment: The report runs against 4 databases with a 5th database holding the variable data. I could have the same table on all 4 but it seems overkill (the table is only about 30 records long and won't be much bigger). From the article above I'm thinking that perhaps the data is remaining uncleaned, but it doesn't make complete sense. I am inserting 4 columns into the refreshed table and then reading only one of them - perhaps this is the issue? The ORA log error reports after 80mins, however I have checked and my undo retention is 120 and the undo used is 10% of the full size so it's not out of space

Comment: The undo on which DB though? Undo is used to reconstruct the state of the tables at the point the query started, so updates on any of the tables involved are important, not just your static table. Which DB is the driving site now - I suspect that has changed with the introduction of the remote static table, and that has affected the execution plan; slowing it down enough to hit the snapshot error from one of them.

Comment: I have checked all databases. Undo should only matter if the table used in my query is being used by another process / has changed, however there is nothing changing in the table I am using. The report is based on past data - so again they shouldn't require undo either.

Comment: Have you got indexes on either?

Comment: Yes there's an index on the field used in the not in clause on each of the 4 databases.

Comment: Are you accessing the remote databases multiple times in the same session? Oracle has no way of knowing if there were side-effects from selecting through a database link, so you should always do a commit or rollback after using a remote DBLINK.

Comment: They are select statements so why would it require a commit? The report uses historical dates, so these values aren't changing either.